# Redirect URL's from subfolder to root directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

All the files and subfolders that used to make up our old Flash website do not exist anymore and so the URL paths to all the pages are broken.

We could use help writing a Redirect for specific URL's as well as catch all rewrite rule for subfolders to redirect to the base domain / URL.

ex.) Specific URLs

```
example.com/home.html
example.com/info.html
```

Any file path or image/asset or page url within these subfolders redirect to root domain

```
example.com/flash/devices.html
example.com/flash/images/diagram.png

example.com/external/m2000.zip
```

New site is built with the latest version of **Wordpress / Apache / PHP**

**EDIT**

Current .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/home.html|/info.html|/flash|/external)
RewriteRule (.*) http://qcmresearch.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi George. I have provided the working solution along with a tester for your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below .htaccess rewrite rule will work for you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/home.html|/info.html|/flash|/external)
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

The online working code for the same is at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d8d5211f-8dc4-5bfc-afce-5dadc69e1d54)

The above code will

Redirect specific url's like below to root domain

```
example.com/home.html

example.com/info.html
```

Redirect particular subfolders like below to room domain

```
example.com/flash/devices.html
example.com/flash/images/diagram.png

example.com/external/m2000.zip
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working when I add it to the .htaccess file. See edit to my question.

Comment: Place the provided rule before the existing rule that is after rewrite base statement.

Comment: When I moved your Rewrite rules before the default Wordpress rules it started to work perfectly like you said. Can you explain why?

Comment: because of the previous rewrite rule, index.php one, program flow is not getting to the new rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/" Simple 301 Redirects plugin for the same.